# Calculate value of two columns using Laravel Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I calculate the value of two columns using Laravel 5 query?

Example of my DB structure.

```
+--------+--------+
| value1 | value2 |
+--------+--------+
| 30     | 30     |
+--------+--------+
| 10     | 10     |
+--------+--------+
| 5      | 25     |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to get the total value of `value1 + value2` I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
$topUsers = DB::table('users_stats')->orderBy('value1 '+' value2', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

This way I get this error:

```
ErrorException in HomeController.php line 39:

A non-numeric value encountered
```

Expected output:

```
60
20
30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$topUsers = DB::table('users_stats')
->groupBy('id')
->orderByRaw('SUM(value1 + value2) DESC')
->limit(3)
->get();
```

Comment: It didn't work, I got: ```SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC limit 3' at line 1 
 (SQL: select * from `users_stats` group by `id` order by SUM(value1 + value2), DESC limit 3)```

Comment: Oh sorry, remove the comma after `SUM(value1 + value2)`. I accidentally put a comma there. Already updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using collections

```
    $topUsers = DB::table('users_stats')->limit(3)->get()
        ->transform(function ($item) {
            return $item->value1 + $item->value2;
        });
```

[Laravel Collections: Transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform)